# Nautilus "open in terminal" extension will not propagate SSH_AUTO_SOCK?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gnome-terminal, environment-variables, nautilus-actions

I have Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, up-to-date; `nautilus` and `nautilus-open-terminal` are installed and updated:

```
 [romano:~] % wajig status nautilus nautilus-open-terminal
Package                 Installed       Previous        Now             State
=======================-===============-===============-===============-=====
nautilus                1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7 1:3.10.1-0ubuntu9.7 install
nautilus-open-terminal  0.20-1          0.20-1          0.20-1          install
```

I noticed that the ssh-derived commands in the terminals opened by the right-click "Open in terminal" from  nautilus windows kept asking my passphrase; upon further investigations, it results that a normal shell, started with CTRL-ALT-T or with the dash, I have:

```
[romano:~] % env | grep -i ssh                           
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1153/keyring-S6rI11/ssh
```

while in the "open in terminal" shell I have no trace of that environment  variable:

```
[romano:~/education … -SAP-135/Lab-8] % env | grep -i ssh
[romano:~/education … -SAP-135/Lab-8] 1 %
```

...and generally, environment variables *are* passed to this shell:

```
[romano:~/education … -SAP-135/Lab-8] 1 % env | wc -l      
70
```

Why is the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` shell variable not passed down? Is it possible to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a launchpad bug report for this issue: [#1411174](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal/+bug/1411174)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Pilot6 --- in general I agree with you, but in this case there is no much more to be said... "it's a bug". Will try to see if I can workaround it (not easy).

Answer (score 1):

OK, [it's a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal/+bug/1411174). Probably the `nautilus` issue is launched *before* the shell that sets up the `SSH*` variables.

#### Workaround

(ugly).

1. open a terminal
2. kill the file manager: `nautilus -q`
3. restart it again: `nautilus & disown %%`, in background and detached.
4. close the terminal

Now the new `nautilus` session in the desktop is descendent from a shell with the  `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` correctly set up, and the spawned terminal will have it all right.

Until `nautilus` crashes or die for whatever reason. In that case, repeat.

Comment: Thanks for this... it is so annoying bug and not solved for a year :(

Comment: @jk_ Surprised? It's not a record-setting bug, mind you. Look at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=377621 --- unfortunately it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good solution, I added the following line into the `~/.profile`:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
```

My key is unlocked on login.